# How can I change the keyboard shortcuts of Unity desktop (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, shortcut

I want to change the default shorcuts for some touchpad events and key combinations, for example swiping left or right with three fingers for switching workspaces, using Super + K for opening the terminal and so on. What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

click on

> shutdown button --> system setting --> keyboard-->shortcut

, choose one element from the left list then modify what you want

Comment: Thanks! But... Is there any way to add touchpad gestures?